# Obtaining a handle or UIA ID of Explorer's scrollbar place-marker

Tags: winapi, ui-automation, inspect, hwnd, spy++

If you have a folder sorted by a certain column, and then you click and drag the vertical scrollbar, Explorer will display a little helper rectangle showing where in the sort list you currently are.  This is what I'm talking about:

[image]

I was wondering if anyone knew how to obtain a handle or UIAutomation ID of that little rectangle (if one exists).  So far I've been trying with Spy++ and Inspect, but I can't seem to figure it out (in part because the rectangle is fleeting and disappears as soon as you lift the mouse button).  Thank you for any response or guidance.

Comment: I failed to find out the window and control type of this "*little rectangle*" and will consult related engineer for helping. Do you mind sharing why you want to "*obtain a handle or UIAutomation ID of that little rectangle*"?

Comment: Thank you for your help.  The reason is that I'm creating an Explorer extension that involves placing a translucent overlay on the items view.  The only problem is that the overlay appears over that little rectangle.  I'd like to clip the rectangle so that the overlay appears under it.  Thank you for any information you can get.

Comment: Also, FYI: making the overlay a child of the items view, and giving it the `WS_CLIPSIBLINGS` style, didn't seem to work.

Comment: Are you talking about an [icon overlay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/how-to-implement-icon-overlay-handlers)? Could you show a snapshot to demonstrate "*problem is that the overlay appears over that little rectangle.*"?